# Problem in storing value in database (cakePHP)

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have a checkbox named required,where if the checkbox is clicked its value is 1,otherwise its 0.
The value is correctly passed form the view file to the controller. The model file gets the value from the controller, but the value is not being saved.

I echoed the required value in the model,to check if the value is received. The value is echoed as 1. But in the database,it is not updated.

This is my code:

```
function updateFieldEntries($data)
{
    $this->data['Attribute']['id']=$this->Attribute->find('all', array(
                                    'fields' => array('Attribute.id'),
                                    'order' => 'Attribute.id DESC' ));

    $this->data['Attribute']['id']=$this->data['Attribute']['id'][0]['Attribute']['id'];

    $this->data['Attribute']['form_id'] = $this->find('all', array(
                                    'fields' => array('Form.id'),
                                    'order' => 'Form.id DESC'));
    $this->data['Attribute']['form_id']=$this->data['Attribute']['form_id'][0]['Form']['id'];

    $this->data['Attribute']['instructions']=$data['Attribute']['instructions'];

    $this->data['Attribute']['required']=$data['Attribute']['required'];
    echo " required model ".$this->data['Attribute']['required'];


    $this->data['Attribute']['sequence_no'] =$this->Attribute->find('all', array(
                                'conditions' => array('Attribute.form_id' =>$this->data['Attribute']['form_id']),
                                    'fields' => array('Attribute.sequence_no'),
                                    'order' => 'Attribute.sequence_no DESC'));
    $this->data['Attribute']['sequence_no']=$this->data['Attribute']['sequence_no'][0]['Attribute']['sequence_no'];

    if($data['Attribute']['name']== ''){
        $this->data['Attribute']['label']=$this->Attribute->find('all', array(
                                'conditions' => array('Attribute.id' =>$this->data['Attribute']['id']),
                                    'fields' => array('Attribute.label')                                                                            ));
        $this->data['Attribute']['label']=$this->data['Attribute']['label'][0]['Attribute']['label'];
    }
    else{
        $this->data['Attribute']['label']= $data['Attribute']['name'];
    }

    if($data['Attribute']['size']== ''){
        $this->data['Attribute']['size']=$this->Attribute->find('all', array(
                                'conditions' => array('Attribute.id' =>$this->data['Attribute']['id']),
                                    'fields' => array('Attribute.size')                                                                         ));
        $this->data['Attribute']['size']=$this->data['Attribute']['size'][0]['Attribute']['size'];
    }
    else{
        $this->data['Attribute']['size']= $data['Attribute']['size'];
    }


   if($data['Attribute']['instructions']== ''){
           $this->data['Attribute']['instructions']=$this->Attribute->find('all', array(
                                'conditions' => array('Attribute.id' =>$this->data['Attribute']['id']),
                                    'fields' => array('Attribute.instructions')                                                                         ));
    $this->data['Attribute']['instructions']=$this->data['Attribute']['instructions'][0]['Attribute']['instructions'];

            }

    $this->Attribute->save($this->data); 

}
```

**EDIT**

I also checked if the required value alone is being saved using saveField option.

```
$this->Attribute->saveField('required',$this->data['Attribute']['required']);
```

The value 1 got stored in a separate row in the table for that particular attribute. So what is the problem, why is it not getting saved along with the other values.

**EDIT**

If I save an integer value directly,like

```
       $this->data['Attribute']['required']='7';
```

it gets stored in the database. How?? What is the problem then??

Comment: Are any of the other values saved? Or is it just "required"?

Comment: All the other values are saved correctly,like name,size are all updated correctly. Only the required value is not being saved.I added this required property recently.Earlier I had only the name,size type ,instructions and sequence no

Comment: Wasn't this resolved with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030639/problem-in-storing-value-in-database

Comment: That was a different function where i wanted to save a default value.
But in this function,I get the value of the check box(0 if unchecked,1 if checked) from the view and want to save this value to the database. I also cleared the cache folder,yet the value 1 is not saved if the check box is clicked.

Comment: Turn debug to level 2, identify the SQL code where it's being inserted into the database, and show that to us here.  Also, in your model, in the beforeSave( $data ) method, try a var_dump( $data ) and see if your "required" value is correctly passed to the model.

Comment: You're doing way too much manual assigning. Use the `$data` *or* `$this->data` array as is and only modify the bits you need to. Copying every single field from one array to the other is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with some refactoring:

```
function updateFieldEntries($data)
{
    $tempAttr = $this->Attribute->find
        (
            'first',
            array
            (
                'order' => 'Attribute.id DESC',
                'fields' => array('Attribute.id')
            )
        );

    $this->data['Attribute']['id'] = $tempAttr['Attribute']['id'];

    $tempAttr = $this->find
        (
            'first',
            array
            (
                'order' => 'Form.id DESC',
                'fields' => array('Form.id')
            )
        );

    $this->data['Attribute']['form_id'] = $tempAttr['Form']['id'];

    $this->data['Attribute']['instructions'] = $data['Attribute']['instructions'];
    $this->data['Attribute']['required'] = $data['Attribute']['required'];

    $tempAttr = $this->Attribute->find
        (
            'first',
            array
            (
                'order' => 'Attribute.sequence_no DESC',
                'fields' => array('Attribute.sequence_no'),
                'conditions' => array('Attribute.form_id' => $this->data['Attribute']['form_id'])
            )
        );

    $this->data['Attribute']['sequence_no'] = $tempAttr['Attribute']['sequence_no'];

    $tempAttr = $this->Attribute->find
        (
            'first',
            array
            (
                'conditions' => array('Attribute.id' => $this->data['Attribute']['id']),
                'fields' => array('Attribute.label', 'Attribute.size', 'Attribute.instructions')
            )
        );

    if (empty($data['Attribute']['name']))
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['label'] = $tempAttr['Attribute']['label'];
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['label'] = $data['Attribute']['name'];
    }

    if (empty($data['Attribute']['size']))
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['size'] = $tempAttr['Attribute']['size'];
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['size'] = $data['Attribute']['size'];
    }

    if (empty($data['Attribute']['instructions']))
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['instructions'] = $tempAttr['Attribute']['instructions'];
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['Attribute']['instructions'] = $data['Attribute']['instructions'];
    }

    $this->Attribute->save($this->data); 
}
```

**Then** I'd try Travis Leleu's recommendation of actually debugging your code. I'd start by checking the value of `$this->Attribute->id` before saving.